# Plotting vertical lines without changing plot range with TwoAxisListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot vertical lines given by some equation in my code below. I want this vertical line to touch x-axis with years and the axis directly above it which closes the graph at a point `x=year` specified by the equation. My problem is that whenever I change the `y` value on the line to get line that touches the base of x-axis and the axis above it the `PlotRange` of left and right axes change and my line doesn't "close the plot".

The question may be frased differently: How to plot vertical line that touches  x-axis(the one with years) at some specified point `x=year` and the axis above it, therefore closing the graph ?

Let me say that I tried GridLines but somehow they don't show up if I use `TwoAxisListLinePlot`. 
Edit: The code should be extensible to more lines that one.

```
  TwoAxisListLinePlot[{f_, g_}, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
   ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], Black, 12], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], Black, 12], 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
grange} = 
 Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]] & /@ {fgraph, 
 ggraph};
 fticks = 
  Last[Ticks /. 
  AbsoluteOptions[fgraph, 
   Ticks]] /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue :> ColorData[1][1] ;
  gticks = (MapAt[Function[r, Rescale[r, grange, frange]], #, {1}] & /@
   Last[Ticks /. 
    AbsoluteOptions[ggraph, 
     Ticks]]) /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue -> ColorData[1][2];
   Show[fgraph, 
 ggraph /. 
Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
 Graphics[
  GeometricTransformation[graph, 
   RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[ListLinePlot]]]]]



 pareto1 = {{2000, 1.254221127}, {2001, 1.347243255}, {2002, 
1.38218106}, {2003, 1.313844733}, {2004, 1.3734142182}, {2005, 
1.298813854}, {2006, 1.253782028}, {2007, 1.2306716}, {2008, 
1.3409995784}, {2009, 1.21464622}, {2010, 1.1720606}, {2011, 
1.24292400036}, {2012, 1.19382731433}, {2013, 
1.22420356414}, {2014, 1.2223526}, {2015, 1.307600821757}};
pareto2 = {{1995, 1.677402}, {1999, 1.7299}, {1998, 1.8988961}, {1997,
1.8543884}, {2006, 3.2155496200}, {2007, 2.242218}, {2008, 
 3.892772}, {2009, 2.937621}, {2010, 2.055810}, {2012, 
 2.03939198}, {2014, 1.76645}, {2015, 1.661591900}, {2013, 1.7859}}

c2002 = Normal@
ContourPlot[x == 2002, {x, 1995, 2015}, {y, 1, 1.43}, 
ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.0015], Dashed}];
ab = TwoAxisListLinePlot[{pareto1, pareto2}, 
Joined -> True, {Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "", PlotRange -> All, 
Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}, 
ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", ""}}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], Black, 12], 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.002], Black, 12], 
PlotRange -> {0, 6}];
Show[ab, c2002]
```

Comment: `Show[ab, Epilog -> Cases[c2002, {___, _Line}, Infinity]]`

Comment: It works, can you make it an answer?

Comment: By the way, when I try to add a second line it doesn't work. Can I somehow extend your method?

Comment: see the revised version below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, when you combine the two plots, it seems to take the plot range from the second plot rather than the first.  One way to fix this is to use the `Graphics` primitives from the contour plot as an `Epilog` for the first.

Look at the `InputForm` of the contour plot:

```
Short@InputForm@c2002
(* Graphics[{{{}, {}, Tooltip[{Directive[<<4>>], Line[<<1>>]}, <<1>>]}}, {<<11>>}] *)
```

It's just a `Graphics` object.  We need to just get whatever is the first argument of that `Graphics` to use as our `Epilog`,

```
First@Apply[List]@c2002//Short
(* {{{},{},{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1.6],,<<9>>[<<7>>],Dashing[{Small,Small}]],<<1>>}}} *)

Show[ab, Epilog -> First@Apply[List]@c2002]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works no matter how many lines you had in your `ContourPlot`,

```
c200206 = 
 Normal@ContourPlot[{x == 2002, x == 2006}, {x, 1995, 2015}, {y, 1, 
    1.43}, ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.0015], Dashed}, {Red, 
      Thickness[0.0015], Dashed}}];
Show[ab, Epilog -> First@Apply[List]@c200206]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As an aside, there are much easier ways to get a vertical line than using `ContourPlot`,

```
Show[ab, Epilog -> {Thick, Dashed, Red, Line[{{2002, 1}, {2002, 2}}]}]
```